# Elastic search multiple regex search within same column in single request?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Using java client for elastic search, I can able to use only one regex pattern search. For now, I'm using like this.

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("name", "AB.*"));
```

But I need elastic search equivalent of

```
SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE 'AB%' OR 'SID%'
```

I am using RestHighLevelClient. Is there any way to do multiple regex search within same column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both regexp queries inside a `bool/should`:

```
QueryBuilder first = QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("name", "AB.*");
QueryBuilder second = QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("name", "SID.*");
QueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .should(first)
   .should(second);
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
```

Comment: Dear Val,
This way is working fine. But while working with large data, it is taking so much time. I think i'm missing some configurations. Can you help me with this?

Comment: using a regexp query over a large set of data is probably the worst solution to take. if you're only interested in prefixes, you can try the prefix query instead. give it a shot